# Dynamically hide/show row data in HTML sortable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am trying to create a dynamic table with 4 columns ID, Description, Folder and Status to display the output of my program. Using the DataTable plugin, I have managed to create a multi-column sortable table. The problem I am facing is, instead of the following table:

```
==========================================
ID   |    Description      |Folder |Status
==========================================
a    |description1         |folder1| Pass
a    |description1         |folder2| Fail
b    |description2         |folder1| Pass
```

I want to create the following table ie. if 2 or more consecutive rows show the same ID, the ID and description of rows after the first row is empty.

```
==========================================
ID   |    Description      |Folder |Status
==========================================
a    |description1         |folder1| Pass
     |                     |folder2| Fail
b    |description2         |folder1| Pass
```

Below is my current sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h2></h2>
    <table id="sequence" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                            <th width="10%">ID</th>
                            <th width="42%">Description</th>
                            <th width="10%">Status</th>
                            <th width="10%">Folder</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Folder</th>
                    </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                            <td align="center">11</td>
                            <td>(description/summary here)</td>
                            <td align="center">Pass</td>
                            <td align="center">folder1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td align="center">11</td>
                            <td>(description/summary here)</td>
                            <td align="center">Fail</td>
                            <td align="center">folder2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td align="center">13</td>
                            <td>(description/summary here)</td>
                            <td align="center">Pass</td>
                            <td align="center">folder1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td align="center">14</td>
                            <td>(description/summary here)</td>
                            <td align="center">Pass</td>
                            <td align="center">folder3</td>
                    </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#sequence').DataTable({
                    //For sorting by 1st column
                "order": [[0, "asc"]],

                //For multi-column sorting
                "columnDefs": [ {
                            targets: [ 0 ],
                            orderData: [ 0, 1 ]
                                    }, {
                            targets: [ 1 ],
                            orderData: [ 1, 0 ]
                            }, {
                            targets: [ 3 ],
                            orderData: [ 3, 0 ]
                            } ],
                            stateSave: true,
                            scrollY: '70vh',
                            scrollCollapse: true,
                            paging: false
            });
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          var rows = $('#sequence tbody >tr');
          var columns;
          var ID, summary; var prevID = ""; var prevSumm = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

              columns = $(rows[i]).find('td');
              ID = $(columns[0]).html();
              summary = $(columns[1]).html();
              console.log(ID);
              console.log(summary);
              if (ID ==prevID) {
                  $(columns[0]).css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
                  $(columns[1]).css('visibility', 'hidden');
              } else {
                  $(columns[0]).css('visibility', 'visible'); 
                  $(columns[1]).css('visibility', 'visible');
                  prevID = ID; prevSumm = summary;
              }
          }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        });
    </script>
```

This code works fine at first load, but table entries that have been set to `hidden` are forever hidden. Hence, I think I need the code enclosed in `///////` to be executed every time display order is rearranged. Eg when the table at the top is re-sorted according to Folder column, this should be displayed, ie. when the rearrangement happens such that no consecutive IDs are identical, all the previously hidden IDs are set back to visible:

```
==========================================
ID   |    Description      |Folder |Status
==========================================
a    |description1         |folder1| Pass
b    |description2         |folder1| Pass
a    |description1         |folder2| Fail
```

I am having trouble doing this. As I have very limited knowledge with javascript & jquery and have been surviving with just DataTables, any (simple) solution/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if (ID ==prevID) {...} else {...}` change to: $(columns[0]).css('visibility', 'visible');  $(columns[1]).css('visibility', 'visible'); `if (ID ==prevID) { $(columns[0]).css('visibility', 'hidden');  $(columns[1]).css('visibility', 'hidden'); } prevID = ID; prevSumm = summary;
              `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add event handler for the order event.

```
function compactDataTable() {

          var rows = $('#sequence tbody >tr');
          var columns;
          var ID, summary; var prevID = ""; var prevSumm = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

              columns = $(rows[i]).find('td');
              ID = $(columns[0]).html();
              summary = $(columns[1]).html();
              console.log(ID);
              console.log(summary);
                  $(columns[0]).css('visibility', 'visible'); 
                  $(columns[1]).css('visibility', 'visible');
              if (ID ==prevID) {
                  $(columns[0]).css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
                  $(columns[1]).css('visibility', 'hidden');
              } else {
                  prevID = ID; prevSumm = summary;
              }
          }
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    var dataTable = $('#sequence').DataTable({
        //For sorting by 1st column
        "order": [[0, "asc"]],

        //For multi-column sorting
        "columnDefs": [ {
                    targets: [ 0 ],
                    orderData: [ 0, 1 ]
                            }, {
                    targets: [ 1 ],
                    orderData: [ 1, 0 ]
                    }, {
                    targets: [ 3 ],
                    orderData: [ 3, 0 ]
                    } ],
                    stateSave: true,
                    scrollY: '70vh',
                    scrollCollapse: true,
                    paging: false
    });

    compactDataTable();

    // With Draw event you catch order and filter 
    dataTable.on( 'draw.dt', compactDataTable);

});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/983e0h6j/1/)

Comment: omg THANK YOU!!!!!! I have been spending the whole day on this, thanks so much for your answer! :D

Comment: Hmm I wanted to try adding `dataTable.on( 'search.dt', compactDataTable);` as after each search the table still doesnt display properly (eg empty cells remain empty even no duplicate content) until I reload the page. Do you also know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer, replace 'order.dt' with 'draw.dt' for catch order and filter event, see JSFiddle